# Помогите разобраться с тем как обращаться к $_GET

Tags: php, global-variables

Вобщем есть простой код...

```
if(isset($_GET['link']){}
```

Когда я обращаюсь к $_GET мой NetBeans пишет мне, что я не должен обращаться к суперглобальному массиву напрямую. Покурил форумы, повтыкал на примеры, но все примеры написанные в интернете так и используют. Вопрос в том - как делать то?

И попутно хочу спросить. Если я проверяю с помощью isset есть ли такой-то GET, то безопасно ли это? Я имею ввиду, чтобы нельзя было засунуть в $GET['link'] что-то плохое, что может прервать выполнение моего кода.

Comment: Использовать isset() безопасно. Такая проверка даст вам ответ, существует ли элемент массива с ключом link, значение которого не null. И больше ничего. При этом в link можно засунуть что-угодно. Вопрос в том, где и как вы это будете использовать. Выводить пользователю? Записывать в БД? Запускать ракету? Т.е. вам нужно определить критерии "чего-то плохого" и сделать соответствующие проверки.

Comment: Проверка на существование, сравнение переменных достаточно безопасно, чтобы использовать их без оглядки. Применение простеньких фильтров, при получении переменной, обезопасит код на 99% вне зависимости от дальнейшего использования. те желательна конструкция вида `$mygetvar=addslashes($_GET['var'])`

Comment: @ganz конструкция `$mygetvar=addslashes($_GET['var'])` нежелательна. Любые экранирования надо делать по месту использования переменной. Например запись в базу потребует `mysqli_escape_string`, вывод в html -- `htmlspecialchars`, использование в regex  -- `preg_quote` и тд. При присваивании лучше оставить всё без экранирования.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Суперглобальные массивы таят в себе опасность. Возможность обратится к ним из любого места приводит к злоупотреблению и ситуациям типа:

```php
<?php // foo.php

$x = $_GET['x']?? '';
// ...

function foo() {
    $x = $_GET['x']?? '';
    // ...
}
// ...

include 'bar.php';
```

```php
<?php // bar.php

$x = $_GET['x']?? '';
// ...
```

Теперь, если надо поменять название параметра x на y, то придётся искать по всему коду `$_GET['x']` и переименовывать. Представьте, что будет если где-то вы всё-таки забудете поменять этот x на y.

Вероятно использование функции [filter_input](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.filter-input.php) успокоит нетбинс. Но обратите внимание, что этой функцией можно злоупотребить так же как суперглобальными массивами.

Ответственный разработчик строго определяет место, в котором он обращается к суперглобальным массивам. Часто это происходит только в одном месте -- при вызове конструктора объекта HttpRequest (например [в симфони](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#request)). Но если у вас просто набор скриптов, то соглашения использовать обращения к суперглобальным массивам только в точках входа, в начале файла может быть достаточно.

Конструкция `if (isset($_GET['foo'])) {/* сделать что-то кроме присвоения значения переменной */}` плохая по той причине, что может возникнуть необходимость повторять её снова. Допустим надо вывести сообщение:

```php
<?php

echo 'Вам письмо';
if (isset($_GET['from'])) {
    echo ' от ' . htmlspecialchars($_GET['from']);
}

echo "\n\nLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua\n\n";

if (isset($_GET['from'])) {
    echo 'С наилучшими пожеланиями. Ваш ' . htmlspecialchars($_GET['from']) . "\n\n";
}
```

Получается мы обращаемся к $_GET четыре раза в разных местах! Так не годится. Правильнее будет получить значение один раз в начале скрипта и больше не трогать `$_GET['from']`:

```php
<?php

$from = $_GET['from']?? '';

echo 'Вам письмо';
if ($from) {
    echo ' от ' . htmlspecialchars($from);
}

echo "\n\nLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua\n\n";

if ($from) {
    echo 'С наилучшими пожеланиями. Ваш ' . htmlspecialchars($from) . "\n\n";
}
```

Так гораздо лучше:

- Вы можете легко изменить название параметра `from` при необходимости;
- Если вы допустили ошибку при присвоении `$from` (например написали в слове 'frоm' русскую о), то обнаружить её гораздо проще;
- Если вы захотите найти все использования $from, то ваша IDE вам сможет помочь.

Нетбинс всё ещё может ругаться на прямое обращение к $_GET. Если вас это беспокоит, замените его на `filter_input`.

---

Про безопасность. Само по себе присвоение `$foo = $_GET['foo']?? '';` безопасно. Но помните, что в $foo могут быть любые данные. Нельзя вставлять их в HTML, SQL, regex, sh и любой другой специальный формат без соответствующей обработки.

Comment: Хороший ответ и по делу. Но одна формулировка, на мой взгляд, может кем-то быть воспринята неправильно. Это не конструкция `if (isset($_GET['foo'])) {}` плохая по той причине, что может возникнуть необходимость повторять её снова. Это сам подход с такими повторениями плохой. Аналогично можно и filter_input назвать плохой конструкцией в этом контексте.

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey сам по себе if isset не плохой, конечно. Но в случае работы с суперглобальными массивами его лучше избегать. А вот filter_input действительно плохой, так как он подразумевает, что мы применим к результату фильтры, которые могут зависеть от контекста. Получается, что такой интерфейс подразумевает дёрганье filter_input из самых разных мест кода. Поэтому для очистки и фильтрации лучше пользоваться filter_var. Простой кейс: пользователь ввёл кривой имейл, почту на него мы не отправим -- false, а в HTML-инпут его вставить надо (чтобы юзер мог исправить опечатку).

Comment: _"подразумевает, что мы применим к результату фильтры"_ - нет, не подразумевает. FILTER_DEFAULT - по умолчанию, и тогда мы получаем значение без обращения к $_GET непосредственно, и без фильтрации. _"в случае работы с суперглобальными массивами его лучше избегать"_ - вот это я и не могу понять, почему надо избегать именно isset в этом случае? В вашем последнем коде, мы получаем значение один раз в начале скрипта так: `$from = $_GET['from']?? ''`. Чем эта конструкция лучше остальных вариантов? И почему именно конструкция с isset плохая?

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey Ну другие-то фильтры есть. Их можно указать. Выходит, что автор подразумевал такое использование. На php.net даже пример приведён, где мы получаем значение два раза (там это рядышком, а в реальном коде будет далеко). Можно принять соглашение использовать только FILTER_DEFAULT, но тогда разницы с прямым обращением к $_GET никакой.

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey  Про isset. Сам isset надо применять. `??` -- сокращение для isset. А вот `if (isset($_GET['foo'])) {action}` откладывает присвоение, а потом приведёт к ещё одному обращению к $_GET['foo']. Работать с переменной просто удобнее. Кроме того, if обычно возникает по месту использования (например в шаблоне) и тогда обращение к $_GET просочится туда, где его никто не ждёт. Если `if (isset($_GET['foo']))` --  просто часть конструкции присвоения, то всё ок и это эквивалентно `??`.

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey Кажется понял о чём вы. Поправил ответ. Теперь `Конструкция if (isset($_GET['foo'])) {/* сделать что-то кроме присвоения значения переменной */} плохая`. Спасибо за замечание.

Comment: Да, я также понял, что Вы имели в виду. Просто акцент был не там. Теперь всё отлично!

Answer (score -1):

GET POST одно и тоже но GET отображается в адресе сайта, у меня была форма, `<input type='text' name="login">`

Я с нее проверял через пост,

if ($_POST['login']){
Действие
}

Comment: Да, я работаю именно с адресом сайта.

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста в кратце, у вас в чем проблема?

Comment: Как использовать if(isset($_GET['link']){} напрямую не обращаясь к суперглобальной переменной $_GET?

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста, вам для чего, для вывода ? Или для отображении в адресной строке?

Comment: Я проверяю был ли в адресной строке link и на основании его делаю что-то...

Comment: `if ($_POST['login'])` - это плохо. Такое выражение будет генерировать `Notice: Undefined index: login`, если login в параметрах отсутствует. Поэтому правильно использовать isset/array_key_exists/empty и проверку дополнительных условий, в зависимости от цели такой проверки.